# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, pygame

Full code here:
https://pastebin.com/Ne3dCpzp

```
Dice0 = pygame.image.load("dice_0.png").convert
Dice1 = pygame.image.load("dice_1.png").convert
Dice2 = pygame.image.load("dice_2.png").convert
Dice3 = pygame.image.load("dice_3.png").convert
Dice4 = pygame.image.load("dice_4.png").convert

dice0img = Dice0
dice1img = Dice1
dice2img = Dice2
dice3img = Dice3
dice4img = Dice4

...

    if dice == 0 :
        screen.blit(dice0img, (80, 320))
    if dice == 1 :
        screen.blit(dice1img, (80, 320))
    if dice == 2 :
        screen.blit(dice2img, (80, 320))
    if dice == 3 :
        screen.blit(dice3img, (80, 320))
    if dice == 4 :
        screen.blit(dice4img, (80, 320))
```

Im currently getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ed\Documents\thonk\game.py", line 90, in <module>
    screen.blit(dice4img, (80, 320))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think you meant to *call* `convert`. Not assign it to Dice4

Comment: Please post your code as text in your question rather than relying on outside links.

Comment: can't, the editor tells me i have too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you have to pass an `Surface` to the blit function.

If you look at these lines of your code:

```
Dice4 = pygame.image.load("dice_4.png").convert
...
dice4img = Dice4
```

you can see that `Dice4` / `dice4img` are references to the `convert` function. Again, that's also something the error message tells you (*not builtin_function_or_method*).

You have to actually call the `convert` function so it returns a `Surface` and assign it to the `Dice4` variable.

**TL;DR:**

The lines that look like

```
Dice4 = pygame.image.load("dice_4.png").convert
```

should look like this

```
Dice4 = pygame.image.load("dice_4.png").convert()
```